# how to handle if root level keys are dynamic in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

```
{
      "type": "thirdparty",
      "key": "postgres",
      "host": "test",
      "id": "88c8fo90"
}
```

or

```
{
      "type": "weburl",
      "url": "https://www.google.com"
}
```

Here the keys are changing based on type, how do I add a pydantic model for this?

Comment: Make them optional and assign `None` as default, e.g., `key : str | None = None`?

Comment: Use two different models, one for "thirdparty" and another for "weburl"? I think we need more context about how the model(s) will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two examples you provided (also as mentioned in the comments), I would suggest using different models.

But if you want to make any key optional in your model, you can use `Optional` from `typing`. Remember to set the default value for any optional key.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class TestModel(BaseModel):
    type: str
    url: Optional[str] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pydantic model using Pydantic’s Union and create_model functions to handle the dynamic keys based on the type field.

```
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

# Define models for each type
class PostgresConfig(BaseModel):
    type: str = "postgres"
    host: str
    id: str

class WebUrlConfig(BaseModel):
    type: str = "weburl"
    url: str

# Create a model dynamically based on the type field
def DynamicConfigType(type: str) -> Union[PostgresConfig, WebUrlConfig]:
    if type == "postgres":
        return PostgresConfig
    elif type == "weburl":
        return WebUrlConfig
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid config type")

# Usage example:
data = {
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "test",
    "id": "88c8fo90"
}

# Determine the model dynamically based on the 'type' field
ConfigModel = DynamicConfigType(data["type"])
config = ConfigModel(**data)
print(config)
```